# Alternative to random_integers in NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random

I wanted to create a random `(x,y)` matrix with a random range of int values, so naturally i did this:

```
B = numpy.random.random_integers(2,9,(2,4))
```

However this resulted in A `DeprecationgWarning`, from what i've seen, this means the method might not work in future realeses. 
How can i have the same result without resorting to `.random_intergers()` ?

Comment: Did you read the full message? DeprecationWarning: This function is deprecated. **Please call randint(2, 9 + 1) instead**

Comment: @kazemakase i did, but i didn't know it had a third parameter for the shape of the array. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Use [`numpy.random.randint()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html):

```
np.random.randint(2,9+1, size=(2,4))
```